# Trim unwanted text with start and end index in column

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, mysql-workbench

I have a table in a MySQL Server 5.7 database. This table has a `varchar(256)` column called 'url'. Unfortunately,

The values in this field have a path included and not to be included when importing into a WordPress blog. For instance the url `'time-for-land-audit'` is actually stored as

`'**/articles/2013/02/27/time-for-land-audit**'` in the table.

I want to update all of the records in this table to remove the date format

```
 (**/articles/YYYY/MM/DD/**).
```

How do I update all of the records at once to remove the extra spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('/articles/2013/02/27/time-for-land-audit', '/', -1) AS short_url;
+---------------------+
| short_url           |
+---------------------+
| time-for-land-audit |
+---------------------+
```

As an UPDATE it would look like this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET url = SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', -1)
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index for documentation.

P.S.: Be sure to test that this does what you want on a test sample of the data first! You wouldn't want to be surprised and find that you had ruined your sole copy of the data.

Comment: Thanks Bill, had an issue with safe_mode but ran `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;` and all entries where updated.

Answer (score -1):

Please put your table name at the place of "Yourtable" and run below command.

```
UPDATE YourTable SET url=Replace(Reverse(substring(reverse(url),0,charindex('/',reverse(url)))),'**','')
```

I have just check it in select statement ,it will definitely work for you.Please check snapshot for you reference.

[image]